# How to install spark on a single machine(CentOS) which has single node(CentOS) Yarn cluster

Tags: hadoop, centos, apache-spark

As a hadoop/Spark beginner, I have followed the tutorial in this [website](http://tecadmin.net/setup-hadoop-2-4-single-node-cluster-on-linux/) and successfully deployed a hadoop framework on my single machine(CentOS 6). Now I want to install Spark 1.2 too on the same machine, and let it work with the single-node Yarn cluster on my machine, which means execute Spark SQL on file that stored on hdfs on my single machine and output result to hdfs. I didn't find a good tutorial for this scenario online for the rest steps required.

What I did so far are: 
(1) downloaded scala 2.9.3 from Scala official website and installed. "scala -version" command works! 
(2) downloaded Spark 1.2.1(pre-built for Hadoop 2.4 or later) from Apache Spark website and untar-ed it already.

What to do next? How to change which config file in Spark directory? Can someone give a step by step tutorial? Especially how to configure the **spark-env.sh**. The more detailed the better. Thanks! (If you have questions on how I configured my hadoop and yarn, I followed exactly the steps listed in that website I mentioned before)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use YARN then you have to compile spark using maven. There are various parameters depending on what support you want (hadoop version, hive compatibility, etc.). Here is the link with the parameter details: http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.2.1/building-spark.html

Here is the command that I used to install spark with hive support on Apache Hadoop 2.6.0:

```
mvn -Pyarn -Phadoop-2.4 -Dhadoop.version=2.4 -Phive -Phive-0.12.0 -Phive-thriftserver -DskipTests clean package
```

For running a single node cluster, you don't need to change spark-env.sh. Simply setting HADOOP_CONF_DIR or YARN_CONF_DIR in your environment is sufficient. For non-yarn mode you don't even need that. spark-env.sh allows setting the various environment variables in a single place so you can put your hadoop config, memory tuning settings, etc in a single place. The template is quite well documented.

Just fire up the cluster components using the scripts from sbin directory (usually start-all.sh is enough). One more point - if you want your sparkSQL to use Hive metastore then you have to put the hive-site.xml in conf directory with the value for `hive.metastore.uris` set to point to your metastore server.

Comment: Thanks for answering, I want to question one of your point that "for running a single node cluster, you don't need to change spark-env.sh". If this is the case, how will spark know where is my haddoop/yarn bits is ? Or does it need to know before running time.

Comment: You can simply set HADOOP_CONF_DIR or YARN_CONF_DIR. Spark offers a lot of flexibility in how you set it so its not mandatory that you set it in spark-env.sh. I set it via a shell script in profile.d. Updated the answer to clarify the point.

Comment: @Jit_B how did you config it correctly to view logs of spark job? Currently when I run the SparkPi example, and I hit the "logs" button in the link http://localhost.localdomain:8088/cluster/app/application_ididididid, it gives me an error saying "Failed redirect for container_idididid. Failed while trying to construct the redirect url to the log server. Log Server url may not be configured. java.lang.Exception: Unknown container. Container either has not started or has already completed or doesn't belong to this node at all."

Comment: there may be two reasons - (1) your SparkPi didn't run using YARN. check the list of applications at localhost.localdomain:8088/cluster/app. (2) your YARN application logs got deleted because of retention policies. check yarn.nodemanager.log.retain-seconds and yarn.log-aggregation.retain-seconds. On my default configured apache hadoop installations logs get deleted after a couple of days.

Comment: If you are confident that Spark is running the job using YARN then check the log directory configuration for YARN